# How to find a transaction without full ID

Tags: transaction, iota-network

I would like to know how I can find an old transaction where only the first 20 characters of the transaction ID are known.

I think iota.cool was planning to integrate a search feature, but seems like development has been halted.

Are there other ways to find old transactions (taken place several snapshots ago) in a tangle explorer if you have access to the seed?

Comment: api.iota.fm works on a search feature for partial addresses (not transaction hashes), but not finished yet (you can search for api.iota.fm on Discord to find current progress). For addresses you can also check the snapshot.txt and the list of spent addresses, but that does not work for transaction hashes either. So I guess the only way right now is to download the databases for https://github.com/alon-e/iotaWayBack, import them into a SQL database, probably add some indexes and do the searches yourself.

Comment: that's the way I'd do it too